# Ошибки после переноса папки проекта

Tags: javascript, angular2, webpack

Здравствуйте перенесла проект из одной папки в другую, но появляется ошибка. Что делать?

```
ERROR in Error: 
Could not resolve "D:/Курси Angular4/lesson1/homeWork1/anna-medvid/homework" from "D:/Курси Angular4/lesson1/homeWork1/anna-medvid/homework".

at _resolveModule (D:\Курси Angular4\lesson1\homeWork1\anna-medvid\homework#2\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:79:15)

at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (D:\Курси Angular4\lesson1\homeWork1\anna-medvid\homework#2\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:47:26)

at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (D:\Курси Angular4\lesson1\homeWork1\anna-medvid\homework#2\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)

at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (D:\Курси Angular4\lesson1\homeWork1\anna-medvid\homework#2\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:212:44)

at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (D:\Курси Angular4\lesson1\homeWork1\anna-medvid\homework#2\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:448:24)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, сообщение нормально отформатируй, а то читать невозможно, вот ссылка в помощь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: из какой папки в какую переносила? 
тут webpack надо перенастроить на новую папку

Comment: у  меня была папка D:/Курси Angular4/lesson1/homeWork1/anna-medvid где находился 1 проект, я в ней сделала папку homework#1 и перенесла туда все что было ранее в D:/Курси Angular4/lesson1/homeWork1/anna-medvid .... также сделала еще одну папку homework#2 и туда перенесла другой проект...